# How to change the color of an active dropdown in a navbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

When I click on the dropdown menu this is always highlighted in blue. How can I fix this with Bootstrap or a change of my CSS?

With this CSS element I already tried to change the color:

```
.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active
 color: red
 background-color: darkviolet
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-justified navbar-expand-xl navbar-light">
        <div class="" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nav-pills nav-fill">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="überuns.html">Über uns</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="Konakt.html">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="Maschinen.html" 
id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria- 
enter code herelabelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="1.html">Element 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="2.html">Element 2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="3.html">Element 3</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="4.html">Element 4</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="5.html">Element 5</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="6.html">Element 6</a>
              </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Marcel.rhd For a start your CSS is formatted wrongly. It should be:

`.dropdown-item.active {
 color: red;
 background-color: darkviolet;
}`

Comment: Ok thank you very much im sry ive postet the sass not the CSS. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default css is generated from `nav.scss`

Add this into your custom css file to change background color :

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, 
.nav-pills .show>.nav-link{
     background:darkviolet 
}
```

I would also suggest you to use custom class for navbar like `my-custom-nav` and use as parent for above css like :

```
.my-custom-nav .nav-link.active, 
.my-custom-nav .show>.nav-link{
     background:darkviolet 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.dropdown-item:active` use this

```css
.dropdown-item:active{
 color: red;
 background-color: darkviolet}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-justified navbar-expand-xl navbar-light">
        <div class="" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nav-pills nav-fill">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="überuns.html">Über uns</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="Konakt.html">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="Maschinen.html" 
id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria- 
enter code herelabelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="1.html">Element 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="2.html">Element 2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="3.html">Element 3</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="4.html">Element 4</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="5.html">Element 5</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="6.html">Element 6</a>
              </div>
```